# How to copy one spring bean to another

Tags: hibernate, copy, clone, javabeans

For purposes not relevant to this question, we're making an row-by-row copy from one database to another, using Spring and annotated hibernate beans.

For the most part, it's just copying the attributes of one class to the other. However, there will have to be some special handling for foreign keys. What's the simplest way to copy it?

Answer (score 1):

Objects returned from hibernate are not Spring beans even if you integrate Hibernate into your Spring project. However you may simply copy fields from one [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) into another using 
[org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object, Object, Class, String[])](http://srcrr.com/java/spring/3.1.0/reference/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)